# How can i get a collection of child elements - query returns null using Xdocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Can anybody please tell me why this Xdocument query is returning null when there are elements / attributes that i'm trying to grab.

I'm trying to get a collection of the `<version>` elements so i can read the attributes of them. Example XML:

```
<dmodule>
<idstatus>
<dmaddres>
<dmc>Some DMC</dmc>
<dmtitle><techname>My techname</techname><infoname>My infoname</infoname></dmtitle>
<issno issno="004" type="revised">
<issdate year="2016" month="11" day="30"></dmaddres>
<status>
<security class="2">
<rpc>RPC1</rpc>
<orig>ORIG1</orig>
<applic>
<model model="2093">
**<version version="BASE"></version>
<version version="RNWB"></version>**</model></applic>
<techstd>
<autandtp>
<authblk></authblk>
<tpbase>-</tpbase></autandtp>
<authex></authex>
<notes></notes></techstd>
<qa>
<firstver type="tabtop"></qa></status>
</idstatus>
<dmodule>
```

And this is how i'm trying to get the `<version>` elements:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sgmlReader);

List<string> applicabilityList = null;

//this doesn't work
//var applics = doc.XPathSelectElements("dmodule/idstatus/status/applic/model/version");

//nor does this
 var applics = doc.Descendants("idstatus").Descendants("applic").Elements("version");

        foreach (var applic in applics)
        {
             string applicVersion = applic.Attribute("version").ToString();
             applicabilityList.Add(applicVersion);

         }

            return applicabilityList;
```

Either query as shown above returns no results. Cleary a silly mistake in my query but i'm out of practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are missing the `model` element.

```
...
<applic>
  <model model="2093">
    <version version="BASE"></ 
...
```

If all you are interested are the `version` elements you can simply do:

```
var versions = doc.Descendants("version");
```

Comment: Thanks Ofir, that indeed did work for the second attempt at the query - so that's solved my problem. However, as you can see in the first attempt in the example above, i do have the 'model' element included in the Xpathselectelemet query but it isn't working. I've tried removing the root element 'dmodule' but that doesn't work either.

Comment: In the first one you are missing the `security` element

Comment: The reason for not using using your second example is becuse <version> elements may be used elewhere in the XML document - i need to find them in this specific location. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code

```
var applics = doc.Descendants("dmodule")
                 .Descendants("idstatus")
                 .Descendants("status")
                 .Descendants("security")
                 .Descendants("applic")
                 .Descendants("model")
                 .Elements("version");
```

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, that's becuase it's actually SGML. I just didn't want to complicate the question. I'm having to convert the SGML to XML before doing the query - which is working fine. It was just this specific query. Thanks though.